# Radiobutton is not checked when loading data with knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5

In my page I have created two radio buttons in the following way

```js
if(data.IsActive==true)
            {
                self.radioSelectedOptionValue('Active');
            }
            else
            {
                self.radioSelectedOptionValue('InActive');
            }
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label><input name="RuleStatus" type="radio" value="Active" data-bind="checked: rule.radioSelectedOptionValue, checkedValue: true" />Active</label>
                                            <label><input name="RuleStatus" type="radio" value="InActive" data-bind="checked: rule.radioSelectedOptionValue, checkedValue: false" />InActive</label>
                                            <span class="help-block"> Provide the Rule Status. </span>
                                        </div>
```

and during page load I want to load the checked radio buttons based on the value retrive from my API and I have written a code like this. But the no radio button is selected.

Thanks

Utpal

Comment: What is `checkedValue: true` for in the binding?

Comment: In a knockout example I have seen it but i can easily omit that @gkb

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, removing that should work..

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ygk3j0hu/)

Remove `checkedValue: true` and `checkedValue: false` from the bindings and that should work.

The fiddle is not accurate, but should be enough for you to understand my point.

Read more about the additional parameters in the checked binding [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)

Comment: It is not working during initial page load based on the previously saved data

Comment: can you share some more code that shred some light on how your data is getting populated??